# F# cons operator and list in class

Tags: f#

So here is my question.  I have a python project that is very functionally oriented...but which fundamentally runs with classes...so F# seemed the ideal language for a compiled version of my code (I'd like to black box my source code...the python code is just sitting there in files.  Not cool).

In my python class, I have a generic container--a python list.  This container will contain arrays of a uniform length in a given implementation...

Here is my problem: I need to add arrays to the list after initialization.

What is the proper way to add arrays to the list in the class?

Here is what I have...but it seems like it will be slow, since it throws out the old list with a new copy (right??):

```
 type myclass() = 
     let mutable _training = []
     member this.training with get() = _training
                          and set(value) = _training <- value::_training
```

**However, this fails** (**even after the edits suggested below**) because the compiler claims that the `set` function is an `obj with set` rather than an `obj list with set`, even though it acknowledges that `_training` is a mutable obj list on the left side of the `<-` in the set function...I'm stumped)

What is the proper "F#" way to do this?

Comment: What type do you expect the `this.training` member to be?

Comment: After your edit, you are trying to use the cons operator `::` to perform a list concatenation (`value` is a list and `_training` is a list). You can concatenate lists with the `@` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'proper' F# way to do it is to **not have that `myclass` class** at all. A class with a single getter and setter provides no value over an immutable list.

That said, the above code doesn't compile for a number of reasons:

1. A `type` is defined with `=`, not `:`.
2. `_training` isn't bound by with a `let` expression.
3. If you want to mutate the `_training` value, you must declare it `let mutable`
4. Even so, the return value of `get` is `obj list`, but the input value of `set` (which is the symbol `value`) is `obj`, because of the use of the cons operator (`::`). As the compiler says, the type of `get` and `set` must be the same.

You can make it compile by addressing all these concerns:

```
type Myclass() =
     let mutable _training = []
     member this.training with get() = _training
                          and set(value) = _training <- value
```

but it would accomplish nothing. If you need a list, then pass a list. It's not that we don't believe in encapsulation in F#, but [properties aren't equivalent to encapsulation anyway](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/27/Encapsulationofproperties)...

BTW, it'd be idiomatic to name types using Pascal Case, so `MyClass` instead of `myclass`. The leading underscore isn't used much either, so it should be `training` instead of `_training`.

Comment: 1) this is a sample of my problem.  It is not the extent of my class. 2) the changes you recommended were typos in transcribing this problem to SO, not in my actual code 3) you are setting the value of `_training` to be the individual element I am trying to add to `_training`, rather than *adding* the value to the list, `_training`.

Comment: 4) I prefaced this by saying I am trying to translate python code to F#...not reinvent the wheel in a functional paradigm.  Once I have the class built, I can be all "immutable" or whatever, but the actual class is fully specified in its optimal configuration and is non-parallelizable, so immutability doesn't help in the slightest.

Comment: @bordeo You can't possibly use a setter to add a value to the list because it wouldn't accept the same type as the getter gets.  You could give your class an add method to do that.  A list property that changes shouldn't be slow, prepending to list is O(1).  You could alternatively use `ResizeArray<'T>` which is an explicitly mutable collection.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a property has a type, 
and the getter and setter must be compatible with that type.

If I run your code interactively, the compiler helpfully tells me exactly that!

```
type myclass() = 
     let mutable _training = []
     member this.training 
        with get() = _training
        and set(value) = _training <- value::_training
// error FS3172: A property's getter and setter must have the same type. 
// Property 'training' has getter of type 'obj list' 
// but setter of type 'obj'.
```

The answer is simply to have a *different* method that prepends an element
to the list:

```
type myclass() = 
     let mutable _training = []
     member this.training 
        with get() = _training
        and set(newTraining) = _training <- newTraining

     member this.prepend(element) = 
        _training <- (element::_training)

     member this.prependList(list) = 
        _training <- (list @ _training)

// test
let myList = myclass() 
myList.prepend(1)
myList.prepend(2)
myList.training  // output => [2; 1]

myList.prependList([3;4])
myList.training  // output => [3; 4; 2; 1]
```

It's not a nice implementation from a functional point of view,
but it does answer your question.

Note that if you do want a pure functional implementation,
you don't need a class at all.

```
// test
let myList = []
let myList2 = 1::myList 
let myList3 = 2::myList2 
// myList3 => [2; 1]

let myList4 = [3;4] @ myList3
// myList4 => [3; 4; 2; 1]
```

Now, how to work with immutable state in a nice way -- that's a whole
other question! :)